# mariadb - ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mariadb' (115)

Tags: mysql, mariadb, port, docker-network

I configured docker-network composed of `mariadb`, `wordpress`.
I am trying to connect from `wordpress` container to `mariadb` container.

When set `bind-address` = `*`, it works properly.
But after set `bind-address` = `wordpress ip`, it doesn't.

#wordpress
[image]

#maridab
[image][image]

`mariadb` seems to LISTEN from 172.24.0.3 (`wordpress ip`). Why cannot connect even if there is a listening port?

Comment: wp has an ip and mariadb has his own ip. this is not the wp ip. so use ip from mariadb container for the bind. then you can connect from wp ip to mariadb ip

Comment: You should be able to rely on your container networking to keep the mariadb isolated to the other containers in the same network. Playing around with IPs and names for binding in containers is hard.

Comment: @BerndBuffen I think I'm misunderstanding something. Doesn't an IP to `bind_address` or `LISTEN` mean to allow connections from that IP?

Comment: No, here a sample: you have 3 computer: 1 = pc ip 192.168.1.100 ; 2 = pc ip = 192.168.1.101 ; 3 = pc / server MySQL ip = 192.168.1.102. then you config the bind on 3 to 192.168.1.102. then you can use 3 from 1 and 2. if you want that a user only can login from pc 2 use CREATE USER on MySQL (3) . see: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-user/ . Note a login to the database has 2 Steps. first = connect to the Database Server and second is the login with username and password. to disable the connect from some ips use the firewall. That is not a prt of the database

Comment: @BerndBuffen Thanks for explanation. But if `bind_address` needs to be server IP, what is the difference between `bind_address = 0.0.0.0` and `bind_address = 192.168.1.102`? They both allow connections from other pc, doesn't it?

Comment: @mishy - if your server have more than one network interface 0.0.0.0 mysql will listen on all interfaces . 192.168.1.102 only on this ip . or  bind_address = 127.0.0.1 mysql listen only on the localhost (db server) and you cant connect over  192.168.1.102.